# Deserializing XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have this snippet of XML and I'm attempting to Deserialize it. I have tried the following class to deserialize to but I dont get the address lines I only get the city state and postal code.
Can someone point out my mistake? I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
 XML and class are just below.

XML:

```
         <RemitTo>
            <Address>
                <AddressLine lineNumber="1">Blah blah</AddressLine>
                <AddressLine lineNumber="2">bah bah bah</AddressLine>
                <AddressLine lineNumber="3">bah3</AddressLine>
                <City>Minneapolis</City>
                <State>MN</State>
                <PostalCode>55413</PostalCode>
                <Country isoCountryCode="US">United States</Country>
            </Address>
        </RemitTo>
```

CLASS:

```
[XmlRoot("RemitTo")]
    public partial class RemitTo
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("Address")]
        public List<Address> RemitToAddress { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class Address
    {


        [XmlArray("Address")]
        [XmlArrayItem("AddressLine")]
        public List<string> AddressLine { get; set; }


        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

In code im doing this.

```
RemitTo i;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RemitTo));
i = (RemitTo)serializer.Deserialize(addressReader);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as this

```
    [XmlElement("AddressLine")]
    public List<string> AddressLine { get; set; }
```

`XmlArray` isn't applicable, since we are already inside the `Address` class, and there is no further wrapper element around the child items.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362103/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-where-the-children-are-directly-in-the-root)

Comment: StuartLC I must have spent 4 hours trying to figuered this out. Thank you for taking the time!. God i feel like such a dumb A**.

Comment: More than welcome - I've spent many frustrating hours myself trying to shape xml into entities. When I get really stuck, I tend to use XSL to pre-project the xml into something closer to my entity graph.